# How do I get the selected value from a Select dropdown list?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Here is my code snippet

```
 <select class="slds-select" >
      <option value="Select">Select</option>
      <template for:each={options} for:item="option">
      <option key={option.Id} class="uiInputSelectOption" value={option.Id}>{option.Name}</option>
      </template>
  </select>
```

I need to get the id of the selected value in my javascript controller and need to send it to apex controller method, I am working in lightning web components
Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using the standard `
lightning-combobox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle `onchange` event of `select` tag.

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <select class="slds-select" onchange={handleGetSelectedValue}>
        <option value="Select">Select</option>
            <template for:each={options} for:item="option">
                <option key={option.Id} class="uiInputSelectOption" value={option.Id}>{option.Name}</option>
            </template>
    </select>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
get options() {
    return [
        {
            Name: 'Option 1',
            Id: 'option1',
        },
        {
            Name: 'Option 2',
            Id: 'option2',
        }
    ];
}

handleGetSelectedValue(event){ 
    console.log(event.target.value);      
}
```

and the console output will be your desired `Id` value

---

if you need to get selected value on some button click, for example, you can use [this.template.querySelector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_dom_work)

**JS**

```
handelSomeButtonClick(event){
    console.log(this.template.querySelector('select.slds-select').value);  
}
```